Is there a way to make Leaflet accept long/lat points assuming a spherical geometry?
I have two sets of coordinates: one from a sphere and the other WGS-84. I'd like to get them both into Leaflet. But Leaflet assumes long/lat points are WGS. As far as I can tell, its quite difficult to convert spherical coordinates to the WGS ellipsoid. However, converting the WGS coordinates to spherical seems pretty straightforward. My application does not need to be super accurate so the error should be acceptable. I can't find a setting to tell leaflet about the underlying geometry. Is that setting available?

you need to perform a manual conversion of your spherical coordinates to WGS-84 (longitude/latitude) before using them in Leaflet. Leaflet expects WGS 84 coordinates for the map display, and handling non-WGS-84 coordinate system with Leaflet isn't supported straight from it.

Got it. Is there a library you'd recommend to convert? When I looked it up before it wasn't a closed formula.

@gph I’m pretty sure you can use Proj4js to transform coordinates from one CRS to another

As CobraCodes already mentioned, the coordinates need to be WGS 84 coordinates. They suggested in their comment that you could leverage proj4js.
I'd like to add an example. The use of proj4js is pretty straightforward. Here is an example to transform a coordinate from CH1903+ (EPSG:4150) to WGS84 (EPSG:4326):
proj4.defs('EPSG:4150', 
  '+proj=longlat +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +no_defs');

const inputCoordinate = [47.3774613, 8.5381303];  // in CH1903+/EPSG:4150
const outputCoordinate = proj4('EPSG:4150', 'EPSG:4326', inputCoordinate);

Here is a very basic example on Github with the code above.
